# Running concurrent API calls

Tags: php, python, mysql, api

I have about 140,000 one time API calls I need to do, the problem is that they all take about 15 seconds. This would take about 25 days to do successively, however, I'd like to get it done faster.

I'm planning on dumping the data returned into a MySQL database using a JSON parser and a function that takes the parsed data. I am familiar with Python and PHP.

What is the best way (as in, fastest and simplest to implement) to do a number of API calls concurrently and have the returned items parsed into a DB?

Comment: What do you mean by API calls? API of what? Python C/API? MySQL API? If you mean Python C/API then the only way is spawning more processes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm calling the API for GetClicky - a web analytics suite. We'd like to have all the data locally so we can process it quickly.

Comment: I should also add that we'll be grabbing all the data for the past 2 years (though they limit it to one day at a time) and we have 200 sites, therefore it will be about 700 days * 200 sites = 140,000 API calls and their delay time is about 15 seconds per call.

Comment: Take a look at the grequests library or Twisted. They both implement asynchronous HTTP requests.

Comment: @Blender - What this to do with asynchronous HTTP requests?

Comment: @ajreal: GetClicky's API is web-based. You'll need to send requests to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'll have to try multithreading / multiprocessing.

This will only help if multiple parallel calls are allowed by the API (and if the machine where the API is run is fast enough to process more than one call at a time).

If the bottleneck is not your own CPU, you can simply use the `threading` module, as `multiprocessing` won't have any more improvements.

As unchecked code, you could try:

```
import Queue
import threading

number_of_API_readers = 10

parameters_queue = Queue.Queue()
results_queue = Queue.Queue(100)

for par in list_of_parameters:
    parameters_queue.put(par)

def read_from_queue_and_write_to_db():
    while True:
        try:
            result = results_queue.get(timeout=30)
            #write result to DB
        except Queue.Full:
            break

def query_API_and_write_to_queue():
    while True:
        try:
            par = parameters_queue.get(timeout=5)
            result = SomeAPI.call(par)
            results_queue.put(result)
        except Queue.Empty:
            break

db_writer = threading.Thread(target=read_from_queue_and_write_to_db)
api_readers = [threading.Thread(target=query_API_and_write_to_queue) 
                for i in range(number_of_API_readers)]

db_writer.start()
for ar in api_readers:
    ar.start()
```

The main ideas in this code:

- have one thread writing to the database
- have many, e.g., 10 threads querying the API
- use (thread-safe) queues to synchronize the threads.